# Merge levels of same variable which are in consecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-transform

I have a csv data file which has 2 headers that means one header as a question and the second one as a sub header which has multiple levels or answers for the main header. Current csv look like below table

```
Header  Which country do you live?        Which country you previously visited? 
Users    Canada  USA   UK  Mexico  Norway India  Singapore  Pakistan 
User 1   Canada                                  Singapore
User 2                 UK                 India              
User 3                     Mexico                           Pakistan
User 4                             Norway India
```

I need to transform it into below table

```
Users   Which country do you live?  Which country you previously visited?
User 1  Canada                      Singapore
User 2  UK                          India
User 3  Norway                      Pakistan
User 4  Mexico                      India
```

Can someone help me with this?

This is how my data look like
[image]

My input file look like this
[image]
and this is how my final output look like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First back filling missing values by `bfill`, then select first column and remove second level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Header', 'Which country do you live?'],
                   ['Canada', 'Mexico', 'UK', 'USA', 'Users']],
           codes=[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [4, 0, 3, 2, 1]])
```

---

```
#if first column is not index, create it
#df = df.set_index([df.columns[0]])
#if empty strings repalce them to NaNs
#df = df.replace('', np.nan)

df = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].reset_index().droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
print (df)
   Header Which country do you live?
0  User 1                     Canada
1  User 2                         UK
2  User 3                     Mexico
3  User 4                     Norway
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
print (df)
   Header Which country do you live? Which country you previously visited?
0  User 1                     Canada                             Singapore
1  User 2                         UK                                 India
2  User 3                     Mexico                              Pakistan
3  User 4                     Norway                                 India
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194144/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-merge-levels-of-same-variable-which-are-in-conse).